# compare input array and data from postgres table - find which are the same

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

For example I have array of names:

```
['andrew','vasya','oleg']
```

Also I have some data into db:

```
name    age   id
andrey  12    23432
andrew  13    32432
```

I want to check by one request get all values which exist in db with the same name as in array . It should return me `['andrew']` response. It means that in my array exist one the same value as in column `name` into db. Can I make it?

I can make it in next way: get all values from db and compare it by using some kind of sorting loop, but it will be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `= ANY` operator for that:

```
select *
from the_table
where name = any (array['andrew','vasya','oleg'] );
```

Comment: Thanks ) Very helpful ) Is it return me values which the same?